# How to consume wcf rest using Jquery/WebClient/WebRequest with multiple class objects as parameters

Tags: jquery, wcf, rest, webclient

My target is to consume wcf rest using two ways

1. using Jquery
2. using WebClient/WebRequest

Case 1 : WebClient/WebRequest

```
     string json = client.DownloadString("http://70.0.111.17/VerifyData");
```

Here, VerifyData accepts three objects/parameters

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "VerifyEmail", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        public ServiceResult VerifyEmail(Application application, string email, Options options)
```

1. Application objApplication
2. Email (as string parameter)
3. options objOptions

   ```
    public class Application
    {
       public string ApplicationID { get; set; }
       public string Login { get; set; }
       public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class Options
    {  
       public bool IsActive {get; set;}
       public bool IsRequired {get; set;}      
    }
   ```

How can I send these parameters from webclient and can get the response.

Also we need to do the same from Jquery.

Kindly provide some way to make it done.

Thanks

Comment: I would prefer using HttpClient, as for me it's much more convenient. See "EDIT 1"

Comment: ok I will use that as well , currently webclient is working fine for me.
Do we have any option in webclient to create json data from class directly?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no. But you can use standard .NET DataContractJsonSerializer or JSON.NET serializer.

Comment: ok thanks for the favor my friend.
upvote for you. Keep it up !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WebClient code:**

```
    const string json = @"{
            ""application"": 
                {
                    ""ApplicationID"":""1"",
                    ""Login"":""lgn"",
                    ""Password"":""123""
                },
            ""email"": ""email@email"",
            ""options"": 
                {
                ""IsActive"":""true"",
                ""IsRequired"":""true""
                }
            }";

    Uri uri= new Uri("http://70.0.111.17/VerifyEmail");
    var wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    var resJson = wc.UploadString(uri, "POST", json);
```

**WebRequest code:**

```
    WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    wr.Method = "POST";
    wr.ContentType = "application/json";
    wr.ContentLength = json.Length;
    var requestStream = wr.GetRequestStream();

    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    // grab te response and print it out to the console along with the status code
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
    string result;
    using (var rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = rdr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

**HttpClient**

*Prerequisite:* nuget package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client"

Additional data contract:

```
public class ApplicationRequest
{
    public Application application { get;set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Options options { get;  set; }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
    var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("http://70.0.111.17")};
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    //option 1, you can just pass an object
    var responseString =
        client.PostAsJsonAsync("VerifyEmail", new ApplicationRequest { email = "email.asdlkfj" }).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    //option 2, you can pass plain json string
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "VerifyEmail");
    req.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response2String = client.SendAsync(req).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

*You have to add a check for http error resopnse (either result.IsSuccessStatusCode or response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode())

Comment: @Gaurav123 I would prefer using HttpClient, as for me it's much more convenient. See "EDIT 1"

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

its easy from jquery to call this

```
var url = "http://70.0.111.17/VerifyData";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {"Application": {"ApplicationID": "0","Login":"00","Password":""}},
  success: success
});
```

OR

```
$.post( url, data).done(function(data) {...});
```

And from Webclient use

```
string Data = "{'Application': {'ApplicationID': '0','Login':'00','Password':''}}";
var appliation = client.UploadString(url, Data);
```

While double quote in JSON object is standard but it should still work or use escape character to escape double quotes.

To get more idea about making POST:
[WCF - Post JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654383/wcf-post-json-object)

**Creating JSON other way:**
You can use Json.net to serialize Application data

```
Application data = new Application {AppliationId = "", Login = "", Password ="" };
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data);
```

You can get JSON.NET from nuget package manager